# I want to create an output, but dont know how

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu

`enter code here`I'm trying to create a quick little app that helps me with an excellon header. I've been Learning about Python recently and im trying to understand how to output some stuff from a list that i choose.

I know i need a list of some sort, and stack overflow isn't really being helpful at the moment so...

What i want to do is have something that says: "Cu: Qoz, Toz, Hoz, Ooz" And then when i select which one i want, i would like it to output the selection as "Cu, Qoz" or whichever one i have chosen.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Here is my code so far:
'''Python

```
from gooey import Gooey

@Gooey
def main():
    parser = GooeyParser(description="Excellon Header Creator")
    parser.add_argument('Cu', widget="Dropdown", choices=['Qoz', 'Toz', 
'Hoz', 'Ooz'])
    return parser.parse_args()
    parser.add_argument('Material', widget="Dropdown", choices=['370HR', 
'408HR', 'R6000'])
    return parser.parse_args()
    parser.add_argument('Prepreg', widget="Dropdown", choices=['106', 
'2x106', '1080', '1067'])
    return parser.parse_args()
    parser.add_argument('Align', widget="Dropdown", choices=['1mm Hole', 
'2mm Hole', '3mm Hole', 'Cross'])
    return parser.parse_args()

Opts = main()
print('Cu, ', opts.Cu)
print('mat, ', opts.Material)
print('pp, ', opts.Prepreg) 
print('Align, ', opts.Align)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want to make a Graphical User Interface, look into using `tkinter`, a fairly simple module that happens to have dropdowns as a built-in UI element.

Comment: By "output" do you mean... display in a drop down menu? Print it to the console? There are different sorts of input/output. And what is "Cu: Qoz, Toz, Hoz, Ooz"... just plain text? The drop down menu itself? Buttons? "_something that says_" is rather ambiguous... It'd be great if you could [edit] your question to be more specific, then we can identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try 'gooey', it's a really easy way to create a GUI on a lot of platforms. https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey

```
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser


@Gooey
def main():
    parser = GooeyParser(description="GUI chooser")
    parser.add_argument('Cu', widget="Dropdown", choices=['Qoz', 'Toz', 'Hoz', 'Ooz'])
    return parser.parse_args()


opts = main()
print('Cu: ', opts.Cu)
```

[image]

[image]